# append URL with parameter on page load

Tags: php, url, post

I'm trying to pass a variable value back to the URL as the page loads. The value is not known until the user-agent hits the page. What method can I use to pass a value back to the URL so that value can later be used by other functions with $_POST in PHP?

Quite literally, I want to take http://example.com/album/title1234/ and rewrite the URL on page-load so it's http://example.com/album/title/?ttl=title1234 , where the URL parameter is parsed from the URL (I've got that covered) and then appended to the URL immediately so a later function can use that URL param value.

Comment: you dont have to rewite anything, just extract the sting from the current url

Comment: This is not a job for PHP, but rather for mod-rewrite.

Comment: why cant you put it in a hidden field so that the function on the page can refer this from the hidden field

Comment: The function is not on that page, it's a separate application entirely. It requires the URL param as a go-between for reference. It's a container application that runs in an iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<? if(!$_GET['ttl']) { header('Location:inserturlhere?ttl'.$appendedvariable); } ?>
```

That should do it, I would think, but it seems to me this could be handled more efficiently with sessions.

Comment: this is as close as I've gotten, but I'm getting an error: `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by... `

Comment: The header has to be sent before anything else is sent to the browser, so put it at the very tip-top of your file, right after you parse out the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Why do this in the URL?  Why not render a hidden form variable which will have the value you need based on the user agent you detect when processing the request?

Comment: Or even better, store it in a session

Comment: The function is not on that page, it's a separate application entirely. It requires the URL param as a go-between for reference. It's a container application that runs in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']="http://example.com/album/title1234/";


$url = preg_split("#\/#",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

print_r($url); //Array ( [0] => http: [1] => example.com [2] => album [3] => title1234 )
```

Comment: I want to take the title value, and append the URL on page-load with that value: `http://example.com/album/title/?ttl=title1234`